# Subset removal when new variables are completed

Tags: r

I am working on subsetting multiple variables in a dataset to remove data points that are not useful. When I enter the subset command for the first variable and check the dataset, the variable has been properly subset. However, after doing the same with the second variable, the first is no longer subset in the dataset. It seems as though the second subset command is overriding the first. In the example I came up with below the first variable (Height) is no longer subset once I subset the second variable (Weight). Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

```
rTestDataSet = TestDataSet
rTestDataSet = subset(TestDataSet, TestDataSet$Height < 4)
rTestDataSet = subset(TestDataSet, TestDataSet$Weight < 3)
```

Comment: You are applying both subsets to the original data. What you need to do is apply one subset, save it to a variable and then apply the second subset to this new variable. Try this:
rTestDataSet = TestDataSet
 rTestDataSet = subset(rTestDataSet, rTestDataSet$Height < 4)
 rTestDataSet = subset(rTestDataSet, rTestDataSet$Weight < 3)

Comment: `subset` doesn't change the data frame you pass in, it returns a new one. The original still has all the data. Note you can combine multiple filters in one step if you like and you don't need to use the `$` in the parameters of subset: `subset(TestDataSet, Height < 4 & Weight < 3)`

Comment: @divibisan Do you really believe that though? Seems like just a rant against non-standard evaluation which would apply to all the tidyverse as well.

Comment: @MrFlick You know, it's something I learned when I was first starting out with R and never really questioned.

Comment: @divibisan I’m my opinion subset() (like the tidy filter()) is far superior in that it’s more readable. Sure, both are harder to use in functions but that’s the trade off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying both subsets to the original data. What you need to do is apply one subset, save it to a variable and then apply the second subset to this new variable. Also as already pointed out you don't need the $ when using subset.

try this:

Make some reproducible data:

```
 set.seed(50)
 TestDataSet <- data.frame("Height" = c(sample(1:10,30, replace = T)), Weight = sample(1:10,30, replace = T) )

 rTestDataSet = TestDataSet
 rTestDataSet = subset(rTestDataSet, Height < 4)

rTestDataSet 
   Height Weight
3       3      5
6       1      7
9       1      4
10      2      5
12      3      9
14      1      1
15      3      1
19      1      8
20      2      9
22      2      8
28      3      6

 rTestDataSet = subset(rTestDataSet, Weight < 3)

rTestDataSet
Height Weight
14      1      1
15      3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `tidyverse`? Chain the operations together to create your own logic. Instead of `subset` you can use `filter` to get the rows you want conditionally:

```
library(tidyverse)
TestDataSet %>%
  filter(Height < 4) %>%
  filter(Weight < 3)
```

or

```
TestDataSet %>%
  filter(Height < 4 & Weight < 3)
```